# iPhone: Error and error handling confusion in comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(results == nil){
    NSLog(@"No results found");
    searchObj = nil;
}else{
    if ([[[results objectAtIndex:0] name] caseInsensitiveCompare:passdTextToSearchFor] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"results %@", [[results objectAtIndex:0] name]);
        searchObj = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"No results found");
        searchObj = nil;
    }       
}
```

The code above compares data a user enters to data pulled from a database. If I enter data which is in the database; it works. But if I enter complete gibberish it returns the error below instead of "No results found."

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSRangeException> *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)
```

The results array being null should be accounted for during the checks in the above code, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are potentially throwing an exception on the following line of code:

`if ([[[results objectAtIndex:0] name] caseInsensitiveCompare:passdTextToSearchFor] == 0)`

If the array is initialized and has zero elements, you'll pass the nil check, but you'll throw an exception when trying to access any objects within the array itself.

`- (NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error` can return an empty array. You should use NSArray's `count` method instead of checking to see if the array is nil.

I recommend you set a breakpoints on objc_exception_throw and [NSException raise] as well to aid you in debugging your applications. Then run a backtrace in gdb to see where the exception is being thrown to further diagnose the real problem.

Chris Hanson has a great writeup on how to accomplish they above located [here](http://chanson.livejournal.com/171198.html)

Comment: Using if([results count] == 0) worked perfectly. Thank you for the help and the breakpoint resource.